# Intermittenent 502 errors on web site

Tags: php, mysql

I realize this questions has overlap with other questions on the site.  I looked through related threads but found no answer for what I'm experiencing.  I also realize that there may not be a specific answer.

The issue: I have a small internal application running on a remote server through rackspace.  The server space is shared, other members of my parent company plus whoever else.  The site I have hosted there is php based and the pages that occasionally get 502 errors pull data from a db.  The db is pretty small (around 400 or so records, though increasing, as the site has forms to submit to db as well).  This site has been up on this server space since last April and, until late September, has never had a problem with 502 Bad Gateway messages.

In the last two months I have seen frequent, though random and intermittent 502 messages.  I have tried optimizing my mysql queries through-out the site.  I've adjusted php settings (max_execution_time).  These errors are still happening.

My question(s):
Could these random errors be due to a process someone else is running on the server at the time they occur? Something that is draining server resources?

Any thoughts?  I can provide code/more details if needed.

Comment: Do you have access to run commands on the server? If you have, then you could see which processes takes all the power with the `top` command . That'll of course only give you knowledge if some intensive task is running on your server and not fix your problem.

Comment: A 502 error is not typically indicative of a timeout, but more or less of an internal request within the server that failed to resolve; either due to DNS, or another network related issue. Do you have anything running over `mod_proxy` or are you making any requests to a 3rd party entity where the network request could fail? Log your requests in Apache and use time-stamps to find out if so.

Comment: 502's are generally due to poor IP communication between back-end computers, possibly including the Web server. 3rd party API requests such as Google, Facebook, Twitter can cause these errors when they fail/timeout.

Comment: After digging through my proxy_error_log I found this: It's an error that coincides with an 502 error for that page I found at that time stamp in my access log: 2015/12/03 20:36:55 [error] 27923#0: *90058337 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 174.78.181.2, server: wpri.lininteractive.com, request: "GET /rs_admin/segments.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/vhosts/system/wpri.lininteractive.com/php-fpm.sock:", host: "wpri.lininteractive.com"